# PHP: session variables deleted after adding JS-script for drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, session, variables, menu

I tried to make some pages with few forms, where one page pass user inputs by session service in PHP. First page (started with session_start() ) has a form and after submit second page got these inputs and transfer it into session's variables. They appeared in the form of second page. As this page calls itself by click submit button I expected to see again these inputs in form of second page but I didn't! I made this small code just to check what is happened but I saw nothing.

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    echo 'Yes, I remembered quantity of money, it is:' . $_SESSION['bu'];
    }
    else
    { 
    //not submit? Then collect passed data with POST and put into session vars:
    ...
    $_SESSION['bu']=$_POST['txtbu'];
    $_SESSION['bz']=$_POST['txtbz'];
    $_SESSION['maxb']=$_POST['txtmaxb'];
    echo 'I got money amount of:' . $_SESSION['bu'];
    }
?>
```

After this code is code that include Javascript menu made in Agama Web menu:

```
<script src="menugta01_agwm_popup_engine.js"></script>
```

and each time I press submit button in the form of second page all session variables disappeared, no data presented, like they were destroyed! After removing this code everything works fine, but I need this nice looking menu. Did anybody met  such "issue" and is possible to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have `session_start` on the second page? You need to call it on every page that you want to access the session with.

Comment: Yes, all works perfect without part with <script src=... >

Comment: So you have to analyze javascript. Session is remebered by browser as number in cookie (with special name). If you (or script) delete that cookie you loose all session.

Comment: ps. PHP use cookie called `PHPSESSID`

Comment: I decided to give a chance to another software for drop down menu creating as I was unable to find out where JS delete cookie and make initialization. For now it works good. Thank you.